# While loop to join panda dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, loops, join, while-loop

once again thank you in advance for any help you might be able to give me. I have a data set that has all values for devices on a fiber network, rolling down from a central node to a node's multiple amplifier,and finally to all addresses attached to that node.

The issue is that there can be multiple amps between the node and an address. I am trying to find which node each address is attached to. Each device(address, amp, node) has an ID, DEVICE_TYPE_DESC and a UPSTREAM_DEVICE_ID. So as an example:

```
 ID:1 DEVICE_TYPE_DESC:ADDRESS UPSTREAM_DEVICE_ID: 2
 ID:2 DEVICE_TYPE_DESC:AMP UPSTREAM_DEVICE_ID: 3
 ID:3 DEVICE_TYPE_DESC:AMP UPSTREAM_DEVICE_ID: 4
 .....
 ID:10 DEVICE_TYPE_DESC:NODE UPSTREAM_DEVICE_ID: 9
```

So I want to be able to join ID:1 to ID:10, but to do that I need to join to each and every amp in between. I'm new to python so I'm not sure if what I am trying to do is even possible, but I'm working on creating a while loop that will iteratively join to the device table again, and create a flag that will change to 1 when the join brings in the node, and stop when the sum of the node_flag=len(address_table).

I have written the code to manually join for the first round, and partially written what I think the general look of the while loop might look like. The main issue I am having is trying to figure out how to rename the columns in the right table each time, and then using that most recently appended 'upstream_device_id' to use as the left key for the next iteration of joining. ADD_DEV is a filtered table from DEVICE that contains only addresses. NO_ADD is a second filtered table from DEVICE that contains everything else except addresses

```
 add_dev.merge(
     no_add[["id","device_type","upstream_device_id"]],
     how="left",
     left_on="upstream_id",
     right_on="id"
 )
 add_dev["left_join"] = add_dev["upstream_device_id"]
 count = len(add_dev.index)
 x=0
 while count > 0:
   x=x+1

   add_dev.merge(
       no_add[["id","device_type","upstream_device_id"]].rename(
           index=str, columns={
               "id":"id_[x]", 
               "device_type":"device_type_[x]",
               "upstream_device_id":"upstream_device_id_[x]"
           }), 
           how="left",
           left_on="left_join",
           right_on="id_[x]"
       )       

 add_dev["node_flag"]=np.where(add_dev["device_type_[x]"]=='node',1,0)
 add_dev["left_join"] = np.where(add_dev["node_flag"] == 1, 0, add_dev[upstream_device_id_[x]])

 count = len(add_dev.index)-add_dev["tap_flag"].sum()
```

So the final add_dev dataframe would have 'x'+1 number of id, device_type_id, and upstream_device_id columns. But I know that I can't rename the columns using [x] like I am doing above. Any thoughts and how I could get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Hopefully this will help anyone who has a similar issue as I did.

```
add_dev = device[device["device_type"]=="address"]

add_dev["join_left"]=add_dev["upstream_device_id"]

count = add_dev.shape[0]
x=0

while count>0:
  x+=1
  add_dev = add_dev.merge(
       no_add[["id","device_type","upstream_device_id"]].rename(
           index=str, columns={
               "id":"id_"+str(x), 
               "device_type":"device_type_"+str(x),
               "upstream_device_id":"upstream_device_id_"+str(x)
           }), 
     how="left",
     left_on="join_left",
     right_on="id_"+str(x)
  )

  add_dev["node_flag"]=np.where(add_dev["device_type_"+str(x)]=='node',1,0)
  add_dev["join_left"] = np.where(add_dev["node_flag"] == 1, -999, add_dev["upstream_device_id_"+str(x)])
  count = add_dev.shape[0]-add_dev["node_flag"].sum()
```